# PHP mktime and timezone

Tags: php, timezone, mktime

I'm working on some time related features and I opt to always use UTC times and store time stamps as integers for consistency.

However, I noticed that when I use `mktime` it seems that the currently set time zone has an influence of the return value of `mktime`. From the documentation I understand that `mktime` is supposed to return the number of seconds since epoch:

> Returns the Unix timestamp corresponding to the arguments given. This
>   timestamp is a long integer containing the number of seconds between
>   the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) and the time specified.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

However, it seems that `mktime` is including the time zone that is currently set. When using the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2016 );
echo "{$time}\n";

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2016 );
echo "{$time}\n";
```

I would expect the two time vales to be same but apparently they are not:

```
1451606400
1451566800
```

Which seems to be exacly an 11 hour difference:

```
1451606400 - 1451566800 = 39600 / (60*60) = 11
```

What do I not understand correctly about `mktime` and/or why is the time zone taken into account when using `mktime`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't tell you why it is the way it is (PHP has never made sense to me when it comes to date and time) but there is an alternative function [`gmmktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) which is

> Identical to mktime() except the passed parameters represents a GMT date. gmmktime() internally uses mktime() so only times valid in derived local time can be used.

There is also a [comment on the PHP documentation for this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php#83226) which explains how `mktime()`, `gmmktime()` and `time()` work. Essentially, they assume that you always think in time zones even if a UNIX timestamp itself doesn't carry a timezone.

Comment: Ouch. This is pretty terrible. All they had to do was to always use UTC on all time functions and only incorporate a time zone when "displaying" times. I guess the way it is is because of PHP's "history"... Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Resulting Unix timestamp are indeed encoded in a timezone agnostic way, but input arguments are interpreted relative to the timezone set for current process. And indeed,  Sidneys `2016-01-01 00:00:00` (GMT+11) happened 11 hours before UTC `2016-01-01 00:00:00`.
When some foreigner tells you a time, you have to know its time zone to correctly interpret it, and so does mktime().

If dates you want to pass to mktime() are UTC dates, then use [gmmktime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) which exists for that purpose.